# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' error in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm setting up a NextJS app on my localhost machine and have followed along the great tutorial on the website, however when plugging in my local API I am having problems.

I'm getting an error when changing my JS code. The error is

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
   (anonymous function)
   /Users/mattcohen/hello-
next/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:1611:17
```

Here is my statement for the api:

```
Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/api/mods')
  const data = await res.json()

  console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`)

  return {
    mods: data.mods.map(entry => entry.show)
  }
}

export default Index
```

And here is my page layout code

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Index = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Batman TV Shows</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.mods.map(mod => (
        <li key={mod.id}>
          <Link as={`/p/${show.id}`} href={`/post?id=${mod.id}`}>
            <a>{mod.brand_name}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo

```
...
<ul>
  {props.mods.map(mod => (
    <li key={mod.id}>
      //              here
      <Link as={`/p/${show.id}`} href={`/post?id=${mod.id}`}>
        <a>{mod.brand_name}</a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Shouldn't it be `mod.id` instead of `show.id` ? There is no `show` variable.

Or mayber it should be `mod.show.id`?

Edit: **Debugging it to know what is the error**

First of all you can check what is comming from the `props`.

```
const Index = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Batman TV Shows</h1>
    <p>{JSON.stringfy(props, null, 2)}</p>
    <ul>
      {props.mods.map(mod => (
        <li key={mod.id}>
          <Link as={`/p/${show.id}`} href={`/post?id=${mod.id}`}>
            <a>{mod.brand_name}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
)
```

This way you will see everything that is comming to your component. There you can see if the data you want to show `mod.id` is there in the `mods.map(mod => )`. But to be more specific, you can do

```
const Index = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Batman TV Shows</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.mods.map((mod, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          <p>{JSON.stringify(mod, null, 2)}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
)
```

This way you can see exactly what is inside `mods` and see if there is the property `id`.

There is some better ways of debugging this to know what is going on, but this way is a good an more visible one.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate you taking the time to respond. I have tried changing those and still getting the same error. Maybe I should stick with what I know, PHP! Not too sure if it has something to do with the json output from my api been different to the one in the example.

Comment: If the error persists, maybe it's because `map.id` doesn't exists. You need to debug it. Don't give up man, reactjs and nextjs are very good.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about what's going on in the function where it's getting the data from the API? When i view my api in the browser the JSON code it's spitting out is quite different to the example. I might give Strapi a go and see if i get better results. So much less code compared to PHP, too - which is why i really want to get into this

Comment: Just edit the question so you can see what is comming to your component and figure out why you have that error.

Comment: `.getInitialProps` is defining the initial props for your component, so when it renders, it have the props you are providing. Maybe your api is getting something different and that is why you are having that problem. If you post what is coming from the api, that would be great

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help. It’s 2:40am here in NZ. Will post this as soon as I can this evening.

Comment: {"mods":[{"id":"Vaporesso Switcher","name":"Vaporesso","model":"Switcher","battery":"1860 x2"},{"id":"SMOK Alien","name":"SMOK","model":"Alien","battery":"18650 x2"},{"id":"VOOPOO Drag","name":"VOOPOO","model":"Drag","battery":"1850"},{"id":"Dovpo Topside","name":"Dovpo","model":"Topside","battery":"18650"},{"id":"SMOK X-PRIV","name":"SMOK","model":"X-PRIV","battery":"18650 x2"},{"id":"Geekvape Aegis","name":"Geekvape","model":"Aegis","battery":"18650 x2"},{"id":"Vaporesso Polar","name":"Vaporesso","model":"Polar","battery":"18650x2"},

Comment: That's what in my api json output. Can't fit it all due to the comment characters limitation

Comment: Please add to your question, not in the comments